# Can't run Kubernetes successfully on rancher cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, kubernetes, rancher

## Versions

- RancherOS: v1.0.2-rc1
- rancher/server: stable
- kubernetes: v1.5.4 (from rancher/server catalog)

## Stack

### kubelet

Image:rancher/k8s:v1.5.4-rancher1-4

```
kubelet (Expected state running but got stopped: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247:starting container process caused "process_linux.go:245:running exec setns process for init caused \"exit status 16\"")
```

### kubernetes + 1 Sidekick

Logs:kubernets-kubernetes-kube-hostname-updater-1

```
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

[image]

---

## Run on the node host

```
[rancher@rancher ~]$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Tue Mar 28 00:40:02 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Tue Mar 28 00:40:02 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false

[rancher@rancher ~]$ docker info
Containers: 10
 Running: 9
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 9
Server Version: 17.03.1-ce
Storage Driver: overlay
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 4ab9917febca54791c5f071a9d1f404867857fcc
runc version: 54296cf40ad8143b62dbcaa1d90e520a2136ddfe
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.28-rancher
Operating System: RancherOS v1.0.2-rc1
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 3.861 GiB
Name: rancher
ID: BMLU:ZJKP:HFQG:WYUT:7IDI:NCMN:INOL:VDIR:EFHZ:EE5E:H6ZA:NFJC
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No memory limit support
WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
WARNING: No oom kill disable support
WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
WARNING: No cpu shares support
WARNING: No cpuset support
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

[rancher@rancher ~]$ docker exec -it 1855 bash
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:83: executing setns process caused \"exit status 16\""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch Docker to 1.12.x; Kubernetes doesn't support 1.13/17.0x.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is specific to K8s version Rancher installs/supports, but in general K8s surely does work on Docker 17.x. Unless it was some exception that I was able to run a tiny 1.6.1 cluster on 17.03.1-ce without any noticeable issues. That was set up with kubeadm, though, no Rancher.

Comment: "works"/starts up and supported are not the same thing... "Drop the support for docker 1.9.x. Docker versions 1.10.3, 1.11.2, 1.12.6 have been validated." (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/9a9a2965564304c8520a9d7c3d23eeb93fa9787f/CHANGELOG.md#node-components)